# Convert SVG image to PDF using iText - distorted results

Tags: java, image, pdf, svg, itext

I have a problem with distorted results in PDF after convert SVG image

I use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/svg v7.1.13

```
    FileInputStream svgFileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/user/mySvgFile.svg");
    FileOutputStream pdfFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/user/myPdfFile.pdf");
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pdfFileOutputStream);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

    Image image = SvgConverter.convertToImage(svgFileInputStream,pdfDocument);

    document.add(image);

    document.close();
```

my svg file: https://www.sendspace.com/file/w8h2uc

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="901" height="1295.59" viewBox="0 0 901 1295.59">
    <path class="v" fill="blue"
          d="5.85,6,7.59,9.17H194c-1.42-2.39-3.42-9.31-6.11-10.49M180,92.62h-1.52v-5.1h1.65c5-.46,4.91,5.72-.13,5.1m36.69-6.13c-10.53-10.12-30.28,4.8-18.11,16.21,10.54,10.17,30.21-4.79,18.11-16.21m-9.07,13c-6.15.26-6.18-10,0-9.72,6.18-.26,6.15,10,0,9.72m29.61.71c-13.35-2.1-3.79-16.71,7-9v-6c-28.23-11.18-27.46,30.55.2,18.87l-.2-5.94a13.25,13.25,0,0,1-7,2.12m19-16.52-10.76,21.91h8.06l1.62-3.75h10.42l1.56,3.75h8L264.65,83.64Zm.74,14,3.48-8.11,3.37,8.11Zm29.79-5c-7.93-4.16,1.75-5.47,5.12-1.15V85.66c-4.74-4.1-15.69-2.88-15.51,4.3-1,4.24,6.85,6.46,8.5,9.08-1.07,3.1-5.6,1-8.53-.77v6c10.77,6.09,24.91-5"
          transform="translate(1)"/>
</svg>
```

and result pdf: https://www.sendspace.com/file/xzrtax

Problem is why letter A and S are distorted ?

Is there a bug in iText library or my svg file are "corrupted" ?

Comment: In the PDF some subpaths are not closed while they probably should be. Whether that's a problem of your SVG or of the iText svg transformer I cannot tell as I hardly know the svg path syntax.

Comment: Pasted your content to https://www.svgviewer.dev/ the preview is blank. Maybe it's the reason.

Comment: @leoleozhu
Ye, maybe this example svg is not correct at all.
Anyway thanks for link to this website